# Cordova opens link as about:blank in Chrome on android

Tags: cordova

Every time I open a link from Cordova, it opens `about:blank`

I've tried adding

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

to `confix.xml`

Or:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to `AndroidManifest.xml`

And then i've tried both:

```
navigator.app.loadUrl("http://"+url, { openExternal:true });
```

And:

```
window.open("https://"+url, '_system');
```

All open `about:blank` in Chrome, not Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, there was a strange character before the url

I was extracting a url from the NFC plugin: https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/doc/GettingStartedCLI.md

And the example says:

```
nfc.bytesToString(ndefMessage[0].payload).substring(3)
```

I changed that to:

```
nfc.bytesToString(ndefMessage[0].payload)
```

Because it cut my url off, but that left a strange character in front of the url , but I fixed it with:

```
nfc.bytesToString(ndefMessage[0].payload).substring(1)
```